# how to add subpath to the incoming request URL automatically from load balancer in GCP

Tags: networking, google-cloud-platform, load-balancing, gcp-load-balancer

We have docker VMs under GCP Loadbalancer which gets traffic with URL abc.test.com/EMC.

Now we want user to only enter abc.test.com and expecting GCP LB to add this subpath (/EMC) and then route it to the VM instance group backend.

So **in short, abc.test.com  --> abc.test.com/EMC from load balancer**
I have checked the LB routing rules, redirect rules but didn't find anything which would suit our need(might have been possible with ingress, but we do not have that) or I might be missing something as I am not an expert in networking.
Is it possible to do ?

Below are my LB settings for path rule and Frontend configuration

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I think you could do this with **URL rewriting** if I remember correctly. I got the following quote from Google's [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/load-balancing/docs/https/setting-up-url-rewrite), where I think number 2 is specifically what you are trying to accomplish.

> The HTTP(S) Load Balancing URL rewrite feature:
>
> 1. Reads the incoming URL in the request.
> 2. Replaces the host, the path, or both the host and the path, transforming the URL before directing traffic to the backend service
>    or backend bucket

Another page from Google's [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/load-balancing/docs/https/setting-up-url-rewrite) shows you how to exactly accomplish such a thing with a GCP loadbalancer, independent of the kind of backend you are using.

Comment: Thanks @Nebulastic it was indeed very helpful. I could redirect the URL as required, however, for some reason i am getting blank page on browser.

Comment: Could you update your answer with your lb settings and the result / status code you are seeing? Then I will try to solve the issue.

Comment: Thanks @Nebulastic for your help. I added LB settings to my answer, hope it helps. Also with this path rule i can see it is being routed to required path however no content are loading on the page. If I delete the path rule and simply use simple host path rule without url redirect   it works. Ideally I  should receive same response on webpage unless GCP LB is making any changes (which might is causing blank page issue )when we add url redirect. Thanks again.